# Linq search query multiple tables

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been struggling with this code a while and again, I'm new to this, so please have patience.

The code below works excellent for searching in one table named Blog. However I have 3 more tables, it looks like this:

```
--[FE]
----- [Blog]
----- [Bolted_steltanks]
----- [Mixers]
----- [Windpower]
```

I want my code to search all 4 tables, now it only searches 1 table. Below here are parts of my code:

```
var q = from p in dbBlog.Blog.ToList()

                //join w in dbAlbum.Windpower on p.Description equals w.Description

                where
                    Data.Any(x => p.Description.IndexOf(x) >= 0) ||
                    Data.Any(x => p.Date.IndexOf(x) >= 0)
                orderby p.id descending
                select p;
return View("Found", q.ToList());
```

**Another tiny problem** is the View that are receiving the result. I'm unsure how to create the model, one table works excellent with this code:

```
@model IEnumerable<FE.Blog>
```

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq just like below to join more than one table.

```
from t1 in Table1
join t2 in Table2 on t2.Id equals t1.Id //OR matching field
join t3 in Table3 on t3.Id equals t1.t3Id //OR matching field
where t1.ConditionColumn == value // OR all your where clause to come here
select new { col1 = t1.col1, col2 = t1.col2, col3 = t1.col3, col4 = t2.col1, col5 = t3.col1 }; //OR all your select to come here
```

etc

I don't think it's required to have `@model IEnumerable<FE.Blog>`. / such multi-table declaration

Comment: If I don't have any @model... in the View I can't retrieve any model items and everything just collapse. I've used your code and get no syntax errors, neither do I get any results, due to the View maybe?

Comment: I wrote a new model that included all needed properties. @CodeMad, thanks for your answer, I learned a lot from those few lines.